# How do I select only the 4th and higher LIs in each UL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For this XHTML:

```
<ul class="collapse">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
</ul>

<ul class="collapse">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, how do I select only the 4th and higher LIs in each UL?

I've tried:

```
$("ul.collapse li:gt(2)").css("color", "red");
```

But it selects the 4th and higher LIs in the whole document.  "Four", "Five", and "1", "2", "3", "4" are red.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("ul.collapse").find("li:gt(2)").css("color", "red");
```

[You can play with/test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/c43b7/).  This finds *each* `<ul class="collapse">` then *for each one independently* evaluates the find selector, giving you the result you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Nth-child will do the trick as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapse li:nth-child(n+4)').css("color", "red");
});
```